# R - Conditionally creation of new column and its content

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a question regarding dataframe's and conditionally inserting vectors into them

I have the following dataset:

```
by <- c("hjoerring","valby","hjoerring", "copenhagen", "skagen", "loekken")
borger <- c("Hans", "Jim","Tobias", "Sanne", "Kim", "Lis")

df <- data.frame(by,borger)
```

I now want to add a new column with the towns individual postal code

the postal codes are inserted into the following dataframe:

```
postnumre <- c(9990, 9800, 2500, 2100, 9480)
byer <- c('skagen','hjoerring', 'valby', 'copenhagen',  'loekken')

register <- data.frame(postnumre,byer)
```

and I run the code ->

```
df$postnr[df$by=='hjoerring'] <- register[2,1]
```

But this will quickly become tedious work if we imagine that more observations will be added to the dataset with unique values.

Therefore i am looking for a way to automate the proces/ avoid repeating the same code

ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `merge` based on the relevant columns

```
merge(df, register, by.x = "by", by.y = "byer", all.x = TRUE)
```

OR subset the appropriate values based on `match` between the relevant columns

```
transform(df, postnr = register$postnumre[match(by, register$byer)])
```